# QSqlQueryModel can't get Time from database

Tags: qt, qt5, firebird

I have problem with QSqlQueryModel, it works fine until i want to get Time from database. Using Firebird 2.5 Database.

```
 matchModel = new QSqlQueryModel(this);
 matchModel->setQuery("Select * from mecz");
 ui->matchTableView->setModel(matchModel);
 ui->matchTableView->horizontalHeader()->setSectionResizeMode(QHeaderView::ResizeToContents);
 ui->matchTableView->horizontalHeader()->setStretchLastSection(true);
```

My database data:

[image]

What my app shows:

[image]

When I run this code `qDebug() << matchModel->index(0,4).data().toTime().toString();` I get empty value (`""`).

**EDIT:**

I find a temporary solution. Change query to this:

```
Select id, druzyna_gospodarz, druzyna_gosc, data_meczu, EXTRACT(HOUR from CAST(godzina_meczu as TIMESTAMP)) || ':' || IIF(CHAR_LENGTH(EXTRACT(MINUTE from CAST(godzina_meczu as TIMESTAMP)))>1,EXTRACT(MINUTE from CAST(godzina_meczu as TIMESTAMP)),'0' || EXTRACT(MINUTE from CAST(godzina_meczu as TIMESTAMP)))  from mecz
```

Comment: It should be normal. Try to call `matchModel->lastError().text()` maybe it will print error.

Comment: It print only blank `" "`

Comment: I tried it on my computer(with SQLite) and when I type `01.01.2015` in my database, in thr tableView I got `01.01.2015` too, but you get another format, so I think that your code isn't full. If so, post here full code, maybe it helps me or others.

Comment: @Simplus What is the Data Type of your "Date" field in the Table and what dialect is your DB setup for. A data type of DATE in a Dialect 3 Db only holds the date value portion, no Time portion. A Dialect 3 DB has a separate data type for time values called "TIME" and a "TIMESTAMP" which holds Date & Time.

Comment: @Ed Column DATA_MECZU is "Date" data type and column GODZINA_MECZU is "Time" data type. Db is in Dialect 3  
<br/>
@Chernobyl This is full code operating with `matchModel` and `matchTableView`

Comment: @Simplus, Try using CAST (GODZINA_MECZU as TIME) in your Select Statement.

Comment: @Ed It doesn't work. If I cast it to timestamp i could get time but when i use this `CAST(CAST(GODZINA_MECZU as TIMESTAMP) as TIME)` it not working. I found a solution which is a bit more complicated

Comment: @Simplus If you found a solution to your own problem, then please post it as an answer. Other people might benefit as well from it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Temporary solution. Just change query to this:

```
Select id, druzyna_gospodarz, druzyna_gosc, data_meczu, EXTRACT(HOUR from CAST(godzina_meczu as TIMESTAMP)) || ':' || IIF(CHAR_LENGTH(EXTRACT(MINUTE from CAST(godzina_meczu as TIMESTAMP)))>1,EXTRACT(MINUTE from CAST(godzina_meczu as TIMESTAMP)),'0' || EXTRACT(MINUTE from CAST(godzina_meczu as TIMESTAMP)))  from mecz
```